Has anyone been able to successfully get a virtual machine (Windows 2000 (W2K) guest OS) running on a MacBook Pro M2?
I would like to run a Windows 2000 (W2K) guest operating system on my MacBook M2 (macOS Sonoma 14.1.1). I have tried both VirtualBox (7.1.4) and VMWare Fusion (13.6.1) without success.
VirtualBox: VirtualBox had originally offered a beta version for the M2, which I was able to install and run. However, installation of W2K did not work. Then they withdrew the beta version. Recently they made available a production release. When I installed it and tried to run it, I got a mysterious message (Callee RC: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)).
VMWare Fusion: As you may have heard, Oracle has recently announced that going forward VMWare Fusion would be freely available for public download. I have installed version 13.6.1, but when I tried to run it, I got the cryptic message "File Not Found", with no explanation.
Has anyone been able to successfully get a virtual machine running on a MacBook Pro M2?

Suggestion: change the title and subject of the question to ask how to get either VBox or VMWare running on that machine -- as-is, it asks for software recommendation, explicitly off-topic. Or try at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Windows 2000 cannot and will never run on Apple (ARM) silicon.

You are not going to be able to run a Intel hardware based Operation System (like W2K) on a M2 Mac just using virtualization.
The M2 CPU just doesn't understand Intel software.
What you need is a combination of virtualization and an emulation layer that translates between Intel and M2.
Fortunately an Mx-CPU based Mac already has that included in macOS, but there is (standard at least) no easy to use GUI available in macOS.
Fortunately the Open Source community has stepped up to the plate: What you need is UTM
